# Datepicker on FireFox using Bootstrap 3

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am using Bootstarp theme sb-admin2, I have input date controls that are working in chrome but not in firefox, issue is that input date control uses jquery 1.10 version and bootstrap is using JQuery 3 version, i Used following code in javascript, that brings the date control in firefox but is not able to open date picker,

```
    webshims.setOptions('waitReady', false);    
    webshims.setOptions('forms-ext', { types: 'date' });   
    webshims.polyfill('forms forms-ext');
```

however I tried to set

```
 var j = $.noConflict();
```

but this not working either.

Comment: Provide the html and js code where you are initializing the datepicker.

Comment: html code '<input  type="date" id="dtDateFrom" style="Width:150px;" class="form-control"/>'

Comment: using scripts in master page  '<!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/raphael/raphael.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/morrisjs/morris.min.js"></script>
    <script src="data/morris-data.js"></script>
    <!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
    <script src="dist/js/sb-admin-2.js"></script>

Comment: <!--DatePicker -->
    <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/webshim/1.12.4/extras/modernizr-custom.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/webshim/1.12.4/polyfiller.js"></script>
    <%--<script src="jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>--%>
    <%--<script src="jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>--%>
  '  <script>
        webshims.setOptions('waitReady', false);
        webshims.setOptions('forms-ext', { types: 'date' });
        webshims.polyfill('forms forms-ext');
    </script>'

Comment: You need to put the Scripts properly.

Comment: <script src="[path to your jquery 1.10]"></script>
<script src="[path to your polyfiller js]"></script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked on both the browsers.

```html
<!--DatePicker --> 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.js"></script> 
<script src="https://afarkas.github.io/webshim/js-webshim/minified/polyfiller.js"></script>
 <script>
 
 webshims.polyfill('forms forms-ext');
 </script>
 <html>
 <input type="date" id="dtDateFrom" style="Width:150px;" class="form-control"/>
 </html>
```